# How to execute manage.py from the Python shell

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use Werkzeug in my Django project, which essentially is a web-page Python shell interface. I want to run commands such as `python manage.py syncdb` and `python manage.py migrate` but in the Python shell it isn't very straightforward.

I tried `import manage` and attempting commands from there, but from the looks of the source of manage.py, there's nothing to call, as it passes arguments to `django.core.management.execute_from_command_line()`.

I also tried defining a function as shown "[Running shell command from Python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)", but calling it using

```
runProcess('Python manage.py syncdb')
```

returns only:

```
<generator object runProcess at 0x000000000520D4C8>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could start a Django shell from the command line:

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then import `execute_from_command_line`:

```
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
```

And finally, you could execute the commands you need:

```
execute_from_command_line(["manage.py", "syncdb"])
```

It should solve your issue.

As an alternative, you could also take a look at the [subprocess module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html). You could execute a process and then check its output:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(["python", "manage.py", "syncdb"])
for line in output.split('\n'):
    # do something with line
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is for interactive usage, not something you could put in production code.

If you're using [ipython](http://ipython.org/), you can do

```
!python manage.py syncdb
```

The '!' says:

> I want to execute this as if it is a shell command

If you have pip installed, you can get ipython with:

```
pip install ipython
```

which you would want to run at the command line (not in the Python interpreter). You might need to throw a `sudo` in front of that, depending on how your environment is set up.

Comment: This would be the ideal solution, but after installing ipython, running `!python manage.py syncdb` from the python shell returns a syntax error on the `!`, before and after importing IPython.

Comment: are you starting the python shell with 'python' still? You will want to use 'ipython'. The ipython shell works just like the python shell, but with a few added features, such as the '!'.

Comment: Ah, makes sense, but it doesn't really solve the original problem, since werkzeug uses the normal Python shell. (Unless there's some setting I missed that lets you specify to use the ipython shell)